# Php client and Java multithread server socket twice run (two thread)

Tags: java, php, multithreading, sockets

I make a php client and a java multithread server socket. My problem, when i once connect to the java server (socket) with php client, the java create two thread, and run twice. When i connect with java client or telnet, to the server, it is correct, create just one thread.
Sorry my bad english.

php:

```
$PORT = 777;
 $HOST = "localhost";
 $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)
 or die("error: could not create socket\n");
 $succ = socket_connect($sock, $HOST, $PORT)
 or die("error: could not connect to host\n");
 $text = "Hello, Java!"; //the text we want to send to the server
 socket_write($sock, $text . "\n", strlen($text) + 1) 
 or die("error: failed to write to socket\n");
 $reply = socket_read($sock, 10000, PHP_NORMAL_READ)
 or die("error: failed to read from socket\n");
echo $reply;
```

Java:

```
public class PhpConnect extends Thread {
private static final int PORT = 777;
 private Socket socket;
 private static boolean online = true;
 @Override
 public void run() {
 try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT)) {
 PhpThread thread = null;
 while (online) {
 socket = serverSocket.accept();
 thread = new PhpThread(socket);
 thread.start();
 }
 } catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(Szerver.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } }



public class PhpThread extends Thread {
 private Socket socket;
 public PhpThread(Socket socket) {
 this.socket = socket;
 }
 @Override
 public void run() {
 BufferedReader is = null;
 try {
 is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
 PrintStream os = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream(), 1024), false);
System.out.println(is.readLine());
 os.println("return");
 os.flush();
 os.close();
 is.close();
 socket.close();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(PhpKapcsolatSzal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 } finally {
 try {
 is.close();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
 Logger.getLogger(PhpKapcsolatSzal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
 }
 }
 }}
```

Comment: please format your code ... the above snippets are very ugly and hard to read